# LDAP: getent passwd don't show my recent user addition

Tags: ldap, openldap, centos7

I don't know why getent don't show my recently LDAP user addition.

1. **ldif file**:

   `dn: uid=user1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
   uid: user1
   cn: user1
   objectClass: account
   objectClass: posixAccount
   objectClass: top
   objectClass: shadowAccount
   userPassword: {SSHA}8t8W2kC48FN0QvwQk8JMRP/OQPI75sjP
   shadowLastChange: 16444
   shadowMin: 0
   shadowMax: 99999
   shadowWarning: 7
   loginShell: /bin/bash
   uidNumber: 1005
   gidNumber: 1005
   homeDirectory: /var/www/html`
2. **ldapadd**:

   `ldapadd -x -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com' -h 127.0.0.1 -f user1.ldif`
3. **ldapsearch work and shows user1**
4. `getent passwd` **don't show my new user.**

Anyone knows what's the problem? I'm sure is not much complicated but I don't find the solution.

Comment: Does `getent` show other users defined in LDAP? If no, do you have your system configured as an LDAP client? If yes, do you have some caching happening, e.g. with `SSSD` and/or `nscd` and have queried for this user before creating it?

Comment: It shows other LDAP users but added some time ago. I've installed `authconfig openldap-clients nss-pam-ldapd` and started `nslcd`. Also I added `pam_ldap.conf` in `/etc` but I don't know if is that right.

Comment: Sorry, it's possible that only is showing local users. :/

Comment: So, you first need to get your PAM system fixed to actually use LDAP. `authconfig` usually does a pretty good job to configure everything correctly. Did you actually use it or have it just installed?

Comment: Just installed I think so. I go to search about this.

Comment: Is it right?: `authconfig \
  --enableldap \
  --enableldapauth \
  --ldapserver='ldap://127.0.0.1/' \
  --ldapbasedn='dc=example,dc=com' \
  --enablemkhomedir \
  --enableshadow \
  --enablelocauthorize \
  --passalgo=sha256 \
  --update`

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much for your help. I'll publish my solution for close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the guide lines of @sven (thank you so much!) I've solved my question and I post the answer for it helps somebody.

First of all, I've checked id  `getent passwd` was showing LDAP users or only local users. In my case, it shows only local users.

Second install if you don't have it, `authconfig`: `yum -y install authconfig`

Write the following command to enable it:

```
authconfig --passalgo=sha256 --enablelocauthorize \
--enablemkhomedir --enableldap --enableldapauth \
--ldapserver=ldap://127.0.0.1 --ldapbasedn=dc=example,dc=com \
--enableshadow --update
```

Console write in my case:

```
getsebool:  SELinux is disabled
```

Then configure start on boot like this:

```
chkconfig nslcd on
```

Start service:

`service nslcd start` or `systemctl start  nslcd.service`

Try getent:

```
getent passwd user1
```

Console write the LDAP user:

```
user1:*:1005:1005:user1:/var/www/html:/bin/bash
```

I hope that it is well.